# Start to Finish Relationship Examples for Construction Works?

Tags: relationships

Can you give me 3-4 SF relationship examples in real life used for construction project management?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE! As currently written, your question is too broad and lacks context. List-generating questions are typically considered off-topic here. If you improve your answer with a little additional context, and explain what problem you're trying to solve and why whatever you've done so far hasn't worked for you, your question can be reopened. The goal is to help other visitors, too!

Answer (score 2):

One is tempted to do these to manipulate dates for just-in-time work:

1. Install pump -SF-> Deliver pump;
2. Construct platform -SF-> Platform pre-construction meeting;
3. Commission Eqpt -SF-> Energize equipment.

Although this gets the dates where you want them, the logic flow is reversed from reality.  This messes up critical path and other logic analyses.  Some people have pointed to the second example as an acceptable use case, though I would suggest it is just as bad as the rest.  You can accomplish the same thing with correct logic flow and a zero-free-float constraint (if you have it available in your software) or intermediate/dummy milestone (if ZFF is not available, e.g. MSP.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. And I saw your reply from planning planet thanks for it, too.